# AppiRater - properties and update of app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm wondering on such an issue:
I have my app in AppStore. In this app I set AppiRater, but right now I realized it is done with wrong and weak properties.

I want to upload new binary now. Make me sure please, when users will have updated the app - will it load new properties? While I were testing it wasn't so obvious. I'm just wondering if should I add a notice "please remove app and reinstall it" or everything will be ok?

I'm just in need to collect reviews :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rest assured that new properties will be used properly - no need for users to remove and reinstall app.

You can always check the source code and documentation of AppiRater.